# ListView layout changes not working

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have recently noticed that the search feature I implemented on my ListView has stopped working properly and I cannot figure out why...

When the user selects the search action icon, a search box appears at the top and adjusts the ListView accordingly... at least it used to.

The problem I am having is that the "search" box now longer "pushes" the ListView down instead appears over it.

Here is an example...

[image]

And here is the layout XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClearText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="clearSearch"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#B3B3B3" />
</FrameLayout>

<!-- List View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />

<!--
Navigarion Drawer (Thought this might be casing the problem, but is still broken when removed)

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#f9f9f9"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#919191"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the simple Java code to show the View...

```
/**
 * Show / Hide the search box
 */
private void showSearch()
{
    try
    {
        //in the instance there are not items...a crash will occur when searching
        if(items.length > 0)
        {
            if(searchFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)//hide the search bar
            {
                searchFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                resetList();
            }
            else//show the search bar
            {
                searchFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Library.errorHandler("showSearch", e);
    }
}
```

Any ideas..?

Thanks

EDIT:  I have now found out it is the android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout. If i use a LinearLayout it works fine.

But now I cannot use the Navigation Drawer :(

How would i go about using both the LinearLayout and DrawerLayout?

Comment: Im not sure but you are using the framelayout which causes the problem, try to replace by the relativelayout with the list view below you edittext

Comment: @user2652394 Ill give it a go, however it used to work using the FrameLayout :S

Answer (score 0):

try to this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClearText"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="clearSearch"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:text="X"
    android:textColor="#B3B3B3" /> 

 <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list_view"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:overScrollMode="never" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however i have edited the post, I now know that it will work in a LinearLayout but if i include the DrawerLayout as well i get the same issue